# Consistency Errors running CHECKDB on a couple of tables in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

While running `DBCC CHECKDB` I am getting consistency errors on a couple of tables in SQL Server 2014.

I have tried `REPAIR_REBUILD` and rebuilding indexes on those tables but these are not helpful to repair the tables.

I have the corrupted Page IDs with me. By using this, can I get the exact corrupted rows?

Or else, how can I repair the tables without allowing data loss?

Also, I want to know, how can I find out the exact corrupted Rows.

I am running `CHECKDB` on a table of size 300 GB, which is in a database of size 500 GB. The error that I am getting is as follows:

[image: ERROR Message TOP]

[image: ERROR Message BOTTOM]

We take full backups on daily basis. I have a good backup of 6th Jan 2017 . Post this date, all the backups have corrupted data. We don't have log backups.

How can I do a page only restore?

It is a SharePoint database server. As a DBA without going to support case to Microsoft, what else can I do in this situation?  The application team want to know the exact corrupted rows so that they can delete those rows.

Comment: Those object ID 0 errors are the most worrisome. See here: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/finding-table-name-page-id/

Comment: Is the database in FULL or BULK_LOGGED recovery model?